# Pascal substr equivalent

Tags: substring, pascal, substr

I was looking for a Pascal equivalent for (for example) the php's substr function, which works like this:

```
$new_string = substr('abcdef', 1, 3);  // returns 'bcd'
```

I've already found it, but I always take excessively long to do so, so I'm posting the answer for others like me to be able to easily find it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the function [*copy*](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/copy.html). The syntax goes:

```
copy(string, start, length);
```

Strings in Pascal seem to be indexed starting from the 1, so the following:

```
s1 := 'abcdef';
s2 := copy(s1, 2, 3);
```

will result in
s2 == 'bcd'.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: FYI, the reason Pascal strings are indexed from 1 is that the byte at index 0 contains the length of the string, i.e. `s1` will have `6` at index 0 followed by the characters `abcdef` at indices 1..6. This puts an upper limit of 255 of the length of Pascal strings.

Comment: @PaulR: The `0` byte length storage location and 255 character limit has been gone from modern Pascal compilers for more than a decade now. (FreePascal, for instance, supports long strings of up to 2GB.) The `0th` byte stuff has been replaced by reference counting and other information that is stored at a negative offset from the first byte's address.

Comment: @Ken: thanks for the update - I cut my teeth on Pascal back in the early 1980s but haven't used it for a long, long time, as I guess you can tell. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR: You'd be really surprised at Delphi, then. :-) It supports generics, closures, interfaces, and Unicode, is fully OOP, and targets Win32/64, and OSX.

Comment: I have looked at Delphi briefly (again, a long time ago) - I didn't know Delphi worked on anything but Windows though (I generally avoid Windows), so might have to take a look...

Comment: It is recommended to [accept your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it).

Answer (score 0):

[Freepascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/copy.html) also has a Copy function:

```
T:='1234567';
S:=Copy (T,1,2);   { S:='12'   }
S:=Copy (T,4,2);   { S:='45'   }
S:=Copy (T,4,8);   { S:='4567' }
```

I recommend you see [Lazarus IDE](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/).

Answer (score -1):

```
    function substring(s: string; a, b: integer): string;
    var len: integer;
      procedure swap(var a, b: integer);
      var temp: integer;
      begin
        temp:= a;
        a:= b;
        b:= temp;
      end;
    begin
      if (a > b) then
        swap(a, b);
      len:= length(s);
      if ((len = 0) or ((a < 1) and (b < 1)) or 
          ((a > len) and (b > len))) then
      begin
        substring:= '';
      end
      else
      begin
        if (a < 1) then
          a:= 1;
        if (b > len) then
          b:= len;
        substring:= copy(s, a, b);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Maybe add a bit mor explanation as to why this is the correct answer